# Facebook Places Search API (Graph API) not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement facebook graph Places Search API as per following documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search/

But it always give me an error which says:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "A0LsjgTKgbRETUiLlmPQids"
  }
}
```

I am trying it on facebook Graph API explorer tool. Following is the screenshot:

[image: Graph API tool explorer place API error]

Following is the screenshot if my developer console

[image: facebook developer console screenshot]

I already wasted lot of time with this. Please help

Comment: See that `websitlast_name` in your GET request? That doesn't look right.

Comment: I removed that, and still not working

Comment: @ceejayoz now the request is: `search?type=place&q=mcdonalds&fields=name`

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version6.0

> We have introduced a new reviewable feature named Page Public Metadata Access. **Page Public Metadata Access allows read-only access to the Pages Search API** as well as a set of Page fields and edges that would normally require the Page Public Content Access feature. Apps that have requested only these fields and edges on Pages in the past have been automatically approved for Page Public Metadata Access and will lose approval for Page Public Content Access on May 3rd, 2020.

You need to request the "Page Public Metadata Access" feature via Facebook's app review process. If you have access to the pre-6.0 API versions, using that will work as a temporary fix, but you'll eventually need the permission.

Comment: what should I do to get that permission ?

Comment: I get that, never mind. Its an option on left hand nav in fb developer console, named 'My Permissions and Features'